# Name for a Type of Simulation

Tags: terminology, simulation

I have come up with a type of simulation "game" but I cannot find anything describing it online.

The simulation has a 2D "world" with a number of automatons on a discrete grid, similar to the game GNU Robots, although for an interesting game, their behavioral rules should be much more complex:

```
#.......
#...#...
...#....
....#..#
..#.....
```

Where each `#` is a robot.

What's this class of simulations called?

Comment: So what happens in the simulation? But anyway, I don't think there is any "official class hierarchy of simulations".

Comment: Haha, I was afraid of that.  You could do several interesting things, such as have several different algorithms competing to achieve some goal, be it last-man-standing or something else.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure whether this is a CS or a (board) game question.

Comment: I'm talking about a simulation on a 2D board.  It's only a game in the same way Conway's Game of Life is a game.

Comment: Similar games: [Crobots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crobots), [RobotWar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RobotWar), [RoboCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCode)